# Stepinfo in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, control-theory

I am trying to determine the following step characteristics for a step response in Python:

- RiseTime
- SettlingTime
- SettlingMin
- SettlingMax
- Overshoot
- Undershoot
- Peak
- PeakTime

Matlab offers me the function [stepinfo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html), but I am unable to find a suitable alternative in Python. I did try to roll my own using numpy and scipy, but I haven't had much luck yet, my knowledge of signal processing is lacking.

Most information that I can find on the internet look rather complicated but I do like to learn more about this. If any one could recommend me a good book or other source to learn more from I would appreciate it! Thank you!

This is the step response that I currently have:

[image: step response]

Answer (score 3):

This [discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/python-control/discussion/1022992/thread/3d038097/) suggests a sort of implementation:

```
def step_info(t,yout):
    print "OS: %f%s"%((yout.max()/yout[-1]-1)*100,'%')
    print "Tr: %fs"%(t[next(i for i in range(0,len(yout)-1) if yout[i]>yout[-1]*.90)]-t[0])
    print "Ts: %fs"%(t[next(len(yout)-i for i in range(2,len(yout)-1) if abs(yout[-i]/yout[-1])>1.02)]-t[0])
```

Then you need to use numpy functions in the Signal Processing section to get the other information that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just implement the formulas? (Assuming that this is a second order system / has two dominant poles and can be approximated as second order)

[image: %OS = 100 \cdot e^{\left ({\frac{-\zeta \pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}}\right)}]

For rise and settling time there are a few different approximations, so the internet is your friend.

You could also figure out the damped frequency (from the maxima and minima of your plot data), and use that to figure out the natural frequency:

[image: \omega_d = \omega_n \cdot (\sqrt{1-\zeta^2})]

There are a handful of formulas that relate these various quantities, depending on what you know.